# mahout-math: java:[42,39] cannot find symbol Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mahout

I am using ubuntu 16.04 64 bit os, Hadoop 2.8, maven 3.5 on virtual box on my 64bit machine.
I am trying to instal mahout 0.13 but I get an error:

```
[ERROR] /usr/local/mahout/apache-mahout-distribution-0.13.0/math/target/generated-sources/mahout/org/apache/mahout/math/map/AbstractObjectByteMap.java:[349,5] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class IntComparator
  location: class org.apache.mahout.math.map.AbstractObjectByteMap<T>
[INFO] 100 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Mahout Build Tools ................................. SUCCESS [  5.523 s]
[INFO] Apache Mahout ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.228 s]
[INFO] Mahout Math ........................................ FAILURE [ 27.028 s]
[INFO] Mahout HDFS ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Map-Reduce .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Integration ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Examples .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Math Scala bindings ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Spark bindings .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout Release Package ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Mahout H2O backend ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 33.653 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-11T14:16:29+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/115M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project mahout-math: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /usr/local/mahout/apache-mahout-distribution-0.13.0/math/target/generated-sources/mahout/org/apache/mahout/math/map/AbstractObjectİntMap.java:[42,39] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IntComparator
[ERROR]   location: package org.apache.mahout.math.function
[ERROR] /usr/local/mahout/apache-mahout-distribution-0.13.0/math/target/generated-sources/mahout/org/apache/mahout/math/map/AbstractDoubleObjectMap.java:[37,39] cannot find symbol....
```

This is the error stacktrace

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project mahout-math: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:911)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :mahout-math
```

and pom.xml

```
    <prerequisites>
    <maven>3.3.3</maven>
  </prerequisites>
  <properties>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.clover.multiproject>true</maven.clover.multiproject>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <msurefire.version>2.18.1</msurefire.version>
    <mpmd.version>3.4</mpmd.version>
    <mcheckstyle.version>2.15</mcheckstyle.version>
    <mfindbugs.version>3.0.1</mfindbugs.version>
    <mjavadoc.version>2.10.3</mjavadoc.version>
    <mscala.version>3.2.0</mscala.version>
    <hbase.version>1.0.0</hbase.version>
    <lucene.version>5.5.2</lucene.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.22</slf4j.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.10</scala.compat.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
    <spark.version>1.6.3</spark.version> <!-- 1.6.3, 2.0.2, 2.1.0 all tested -->
    <flink.version>1.1.4</flink.version>
    <h2o.version>0.1.25</h2o.version>
    <jackson.version>2.7.4</jackson.version>
  </properties>
  <issueManagement>
    <system>Jira</system>
    <url>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>

      <!-- our modules -->

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-hdfs</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-hdfs</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-integration</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-buildtools</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-examples</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-math-scala_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-math-scala_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-spark_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-flink_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-h2o_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <artifactId>mahout-native-viennacl_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <!-- 3rd party  -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.sf.kosmosfs</groupId>
            <artifactId>kfs</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>xmlenc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlenc</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
            <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-benchmark</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>randomizedtesting-runner</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.15</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>${lucene.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-mahout</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>${hbase.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>2.8</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <ignore />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mahout-collection-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute>
                      <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                      <runOnConfiguration>true</runOnConfiguration>
                    </execute>
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${eclipse.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
            <buildcommands>
              <java.lang.String>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</java.lang.String>
              <java.lang.String>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleBuilder</java.lang.String>
              <java.lang.String>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdBuilder</java.lang.String>
            </buildcommands>
            <projectnatures>
              <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
              <nature>com.atlassw.tools.eclipse.checkstyle.CheckstyleNature</nature>
              <nature>net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.plugin.pmdNature</nature>
            </projectnatures>
            <additionalConfig>
              <file>
                <name>.checkstyle</name>
                <location>/mahout-eclipse-checkstyle</location>
              </file>
              <file>
                <name>.pmd</name>
                <location>/mahout-eclipse-pmd</location>
              </file>
              <file>
                <name>.ruleset</name>
                <location>/mahout-pmd-ruleset.xml</location>
              </file>
            </additionalConfig>
          </configuration>
          <!-- the 'location' elements above refer to classpath -->
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
              <artifactId>mahout-buildtools</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
            <releaseProfiles>mahout-release,apache-release,hadoop2</releaseProfiles>
            <goals>deploy</goals>
            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            <arguments>${arguments}</arguments>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <!--${maven.compiler.source}${maven.compiler.target} encoding, source and target are explicitly defined until MNGECLIPSE-966 is fixed -->
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <optimize>true</optimize>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
          <artifactId>mahout-collection-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.9.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${mscala.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <jvmArgs>
              <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
              <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
            </jvmArgs>
            <args>
              <arg>-target:jvm-${maven.compiler.target}</arg>
              <arg>-deprecation</arg>
              <arg>-feature</arg>
              <arg>-language:existentials</arg>
              <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
              <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
            </args>
            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
            <testSourceDir>src/test/scala</testSourceDir>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
          <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/scalatest-reports</reportsDirectory>
            <junitxml>.</junitxml>
            <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
            <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
```

Please, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: can you please provide what build command you used and what java you have

Comment: I have openjdk-8 and used mvn clean install, also the with the test skipping but result is the same.

Comment: first thing to try is adding `-Dhadoop.version=2.8.0` to the mvn build command

mahout is built for 2.4, however, I've never had that issue- so very curious if that is what is causing it.